# Jquery UI Sortable exist

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I check is jquery sortable is available? So I dont load jquery ui dynamically in my code in script tag. Something like this?

```
typeof $.sortable === "function"
```

Answer (score 3):

Because sortable belongs to jQuery UI and from its definition:

> var widgetsSortable = $.widget( "ui.sortable",

Your test can be:

```js
if ($.ui && typeof $.ui.sortable === "function") {
  console.log('sortable is available');
} else {
  console.log('jQuery UI not loaded');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

```js
if ($.ui && typeof $.ui.sortable === "function") {
  console.log('sortable is available');
} else {
  console.log('jQuery UI not loaded');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```